# Splitting field extension of degree $n!$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, splitting-field

Suppose $f \in K[X]$ is a polynomial of degree n.

I had a small exercise were I had to prove that the degree of a field extension (by the splitting field of f which is $\Sigma$) $[\Sigma : K]$ divides $n!$. After  convincing myself of this, I tried to find extensions, say of $\mathbb{Q}$ were we had in general the equality, i.e. the extension is of degree $n!$. What would be such an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general the polynomials of the form $x^n - px - p$ for a prime integer $p$ give you such an example, but proving this in general isn't that "easy". If you are interested in a proof you can check the Wikipedia page on the more general topic of the [Inverse Galois Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem#Symmetric_and_alternating_groups). In fact your question is a special case of this problem, where you are asking whether each $S_n$ is realizable as a Galois group of a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general theorem which fits your problem perfectly when $n$ is prime:

> If $f$ is an irreducible polynomial of prime degree $p$ with rational coefficients and exactly two non-real roots, then the Galois group of $f$ is the full symmetric group $S_p$. [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_group#Examples)